# Glob to print missing files list

Tags: python, glob

What am I missing here?

I am trying to print a list of missing files, as example I am using 'WorhSheet_X' and 'WorkSheet_Y' as my expected files, I want to be able to print the name of files that are missing, if there are missing files on folder.

Else, just a why I am trying this to create a code that sends an e-mail automatically when there are missing files, with the missing file names on the body of the e-mail.

```
import glob

dir_to_search = r'G:\folder'

files_in_dir = glob.glob("{}{}".format(dir_to_search,'*.xls?'))

list_of_files = glob.glob('WorkSheet_X*','WorkSheet_Y*', recursive=True)

missing_files = [x for x in list_of_files if x not in files_in_dir]

print(missing_files)
```

Got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): ...
list_of_files = glob.glob('WorkSheet_X*','WorkSheet_Y*', recursive=True)
TypeError: glob() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

EDIT:

I need to search the files with a partial name 'WorkSheet_X*' because every day there is a different date after the 'X' in 'WorkSheet_X'.

Comment: glob takes only one path and you need to do two searching separately - one for anything starting with `WorkSheet_X` another one for `WorkSheet_Y` and then merge these two lists. Glob won't work with two paths which is why it says it got two positional arguments.

Comment: You can only pass one file specification to `glob` at a time, either 'WorkSheet_X*' *or* 'WorkSheet_Y*' but not both. But your whole question is somewhat unclear. Are you trying to determine which files that match the pattern `WorkSheet_X*` in the *current directory and any of its subdirectories* are not among the *`xls` files in the `G:\folder`*? Because that seems to be what your code is attempting to do.

Comment: Like others said, you cannot match two things at a time using `glob`. But maybe you can use the `[]` syntax to match different things in the same place: `WorkSheet_[XY]*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing full path names of files that exist in different directories because as your code now stands, you are doing a search for patterns WorkSheet_X* and WorkSheet_Y* in the current working directory, which would be different than `dir_to_search` (if it weren't, I am not sure what the point of this program is). Anyway, this code *allows* the current working directory to be some directory other than `dir_to_search`. So this code splits the full path names of the files and just compares file names and also attempts to make some optimizations (and corrections to your code):

```
import glob, itertools, os.path

dir_to_search = r'G:\folder'

# Create a set from the list of files to make searching more efficient but use only filename:
files_in_dir = {os.path.split(f)[1] for f in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir_to_search, '*.xls?'))}
"""
Use itertools.chain to combine calls to rglob.
So rather than building an in-memory list, we are building a generator that
will return the filenames as we need them. This is more efficient if there are a lot of files.
"""
list_of_files = itertools.chain(glob.glob('WorkSheet_X*'), glob.glob('WorkSheet_Y*'))
# but we now must separate the file name from the full path sepcification:
missing_files = [f for f in list_of_files if os.path.split(f)[1] not in files_in_dir]

print(missing_files)
```

If we are talking about a really large number of files constituting the pattern `'*.xls?'` in the `dir_to_search` directory, it might be better *not* to create the `files_in_dir` set at all and instead do a directory look up for each candidate file:

```
missing_files = [f for f in list_of_files if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_to_search, os.path.split(f)[1]))]
```

There is a subtle difference however. Suppose we find a file named `WorkSheet_X1.csv` and it does exist in the `dir_to_search` directory. The first method will show it as missing because it does not match the pattern `*.xls?`. However, it will not be reported as missing using the second method by dint of it existing in the correct directory. Should the glob pattern being used really be `'WorkSheet_X*.xls?'`?

Comment: What should i change to search inside just the folder and not the subdir's?

Comment: I am in a hurry and cant test the code right now, but as soon i test it i will get back to you if its suiting me well! Thanks for the support!!!